# NSDate adds 2 hrs

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I will appreciate if someone could please advise me what is wrong with the date formatting. I have the following date as string from webservice :

```
20141211200300 //yyyyMMddHHmmss -->2014/12/11 20:03:00
```

But when I format it using the following format it adds 2 hrs

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:localDate];
```

The output I get in console is

```
2014-12-11 10:03:00 +0000
```

I tried adding GMT timezone as well as Australia/Brisbane still get the same issue.

Comment: Thank you @Zaph yes I am using NSLog(). I will accept your answer.

Comment: oh dear... when do they learn to deal with _timezones_?

Answer (score 0):

You did not show the code that printed the number. If you used `NSLog()` there is probably a time zone issue, Note that the printed time is in GMT. Is your time zone two hours from GMT?